# get all disabled products in current category

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection

How do I get all disabled products in the current category

```
<?php 
    $categoryIds = array(956);//category id
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryIds));
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $products->getAllIds()))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
 ->addFieldToFilter('status',Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);

?>
```

Comment: Have you set the website id ?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to get products from category using $productCollection->addCategoryFilter() or using $category->getProductCollection() query use product to category connection INDEX table. When you run re index that product category connection INDEX table is populated only with Enabled porducts, and you can not get disabled products on that way.

```
$categoryId = 956; // a category id that you can get from admin
```

For Disable Product

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
 ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 2))
 ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id',  array('eq' => $categoryId));
```

Comment: I already tried No result

Comment: Updated answer check it

Comment: No luck i already try this all solution

Comment: It is working for me. what is the error ?

Comment: it shows empty page i disabled 1 product]

Comment: ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id',  array('eq' => 956)); try this

Comment: same empty only

Comment: var_dump($collection->getData()); debug collection

Comment: reindex all after disable product

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(956)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status',
    array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED)
);
```

Comment: No luck i already try this all solution

Comment: did you try to re-index the data?

Comment: Everthing is ready to index only

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code  in Magento 1.9 and working fine hope it will work for you.

```
$catId = 45;
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId)
     ->getProductCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
     ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 2);


    foreach ($products as $pid)
    {
        echo    $pid->getName(); 

    }
```

Comment: No luck i already try this all solution